# Configuring Windows Identity Foundation from code

Tags: model-view-controller, azure, appfabric, wif, sts-securitytokenservice

I'm experimenting with "configuration-less WIF", where I want to accept a SAML2 token that is generated by Windows Azure's AppFabric STS.

What I'm doing is parsing checking the current request for token information, like so:

```
        if (Request.Form.Get(WSFederationConstants.Parameters.Result) != null)
        {
            SignInResponseMessage message = 
                WSFederationMessage.CreateFromFormPost(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request) as SignInResponseMessage;

            var securityTokenHandlers = SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.CreateDefaultSecurityTokenHandlerCollection();                    

            XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(
                new StringReader(message.Result));

            SecurityToken token = securityTokenHandlers.ReadToken(xmlReader);

            if (token != null)
            {
                ClaimsIdentityCollection claims = securityTokenHandlers.ValidateToken(token);
                IPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claims);
            }
        }
```

The code above uses the SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.CreateDefaultSecurityTokenHandlerCollection(); colection to verify and handle the SAML token. However: this does not work because obviously the application has not bee nconfigured correctly. How would I specify the follwing configuration from XML programmaticaly on my securityTokenHandlers collection?

```
  <microsoft.identityModel>
<service>
  <audienceUris>
    <add value="http://www.someapp.net/" />
  </audienceUris>
  <federatedAuthentication>
    <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://rd-test.accesscontrol.appfabriclabs.com/v2/wsfederation" realm="http://www.thisapp.net" requireHttps="false" />
    <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
  </federatedAuthentication>
  <applicationService>
    <claimTypeRequired>
      <claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" optional="true" />
      <claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" optional="true" />
    </claimTypeRequired>
  </applicationService>
  <issuerNameRegistry type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
    <trustedIssuers>
      <add thumbprint="XYZ123" name="https://somenamespace.accesscontrol.appfabriclabs.com/" />
    </trustedIssuers>
  </issuerNameRegistry>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: found a solution and implemented it in a module described (and linked) here: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2011/02/14/Authenticate-Orchard-users-with-AppFabric-Access-Control-Service.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with the same and found a working solution in WIF 3.5/4.0. Since maartenba's link seems to be dead, I wanted to post my solution here.

Our requirements were:

- Configuration fully in code (as we ship a default web.config with the app)
- Maximum allowed .Net version 4.0 (hence I am using WIF 3.5/4.0)

What I used to arrive at the solution:

- Information about dynamic WIF configuration provided by Daniel Wu
  [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/41b9a137-faca-43c6-b965-01d5322df5f0/change-microsoftidentitymodel-configuration?forum=Geneva).
- [This
  method](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/02/register-your-http-modules-at-runtime.html)
  to register HTTP modules at runtime, explained by David Ebbo. I
  also tried the more elegant method [explained by Rick
  Strahl](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/Apr/06/Dynamically-hooking-up-HttpModules),
  but that unfortunately did not do the trick for me.

> Edit 2016/09/02: instead of adding a separate "pre application start
>   code" class as in David Ebbo's example, the WIF-related HTTP modules
>   can also be registered in the static constructor of the
>   `HttpApplication' class. I have adapted the code to this somewhat
>   cleaner solution.

My solution needs *nothing* in web.config. The bulk of the code is in global.asax.cs. Configuration is hard-coded in this sample:

```cs
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Selectors;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web;

namespace TestADFS
{
  public class SessionAuthenticationModule : Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule
  {
    protected override void InitializePropertiesFromConfiguration(string serviceName)
    {
    }
  }
  public class WSFederationAuthenticationModule : Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule
  {
    protected override void InitializePropertiesFromConfiguration(string serviceName)
    {
      ServiceConfiguration = FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfiguration;
      PassiveRedirectEnabled = true;
      RequireHttps = true;
      Issuer = "https://nl-joinadfstest.joinadfstest.local/adfs/ls/";
      Realm = "https://67px95j.decos.com/testadfs";
    }
  }

  public class Global : HttpApplication
  {
    static Global()
    {
      Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(SessionAuthenticationModule));
      Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(WSFederationAuthenticationModule));
    }

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfigurationCreated += FederatedAuthentication_ServiceConfigurationCreated;
    }

    internal void FederatedAuthentication_ServiceConfigurationCreated(object sender, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.Configuration.ServiceConfigurationCreatedEventArgs e)
    {
      X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
      store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
      X509Certificate2Collection coll = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "245537E9BB2C086D3C880982FA86267FBD66B9A3", false);
      if (coll.Count > 0)
        e.ServiceConfiguration.ServiceCertificate = coll[0];
      store.Close();
      AudienceRestriction ar = new AudienceRestriction(AudienceUriMode.Always);
      ar.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(new Uri("https://67px95j.decos.com/testadfs"));
      e.ServiceConfiguration.AudienceRestriction = ar;
      ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry inr = new ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry();
      inr.AddTrustedIssuer("6C9B96D90257B65B6F181C2478D869473DC359EA", "http://NL-JOINADFSTEST.joinadfstest.local/adfs/services/trust");
      e.ServiceConfiguration.IssuerNameRegistry = inr;
      e.ServiceConfiguration.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
    }

    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.ServiceConfiguration = FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfiguration;
    }
  }
}
```

## Usage

My app is asp.net WebForms, running in classic pipeline mode and supports forms authentication as well as ADFS login. Because of that, authentication is handled in a common base class shared by all .aspx pages:

```cs
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
      if (NeedsAuthentication && !User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
      {
        SignInRequestMessage sirm = new SignInRequestMessage(
          new Uri("https://nl-joinadfstest.joinadfstest.local/adfs/ls/"),
          ApplicationRootUrl)
        {
          Context = ApplicationRootUrl,
          HomeRealm = ApplicationRootUrl
        };
        Response.Redirect(sirm.WriteQueryString());
      }
      base.OnInit(e);
    }
```

In this code, `ApplicationRootUrl` is the application path ending in "/" (the "/" is important in Classic pipeline mode).

As a stable implementation for logout in mixed mode was not so easy, I want to show the code for that as well. Technically it works, but I still have an issue with IE immediately logging in again after logging out an ADFS account:

```cs
      if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
      {
        if (User.Identity.AuthenticationType == "Forms")
        {
          FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
          Session.Clear();
          Session.Abandon();
          ResetCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
          ResetCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId");
          Response.Redirect(ApplicationRootUrl + "Default.aspx");
          HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
        else
        {
          FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();
          FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.DeleteSessionTokenCookie();
          Uri uri = new Uri(ApplicationRootUrl + "Default.aspx");
          WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut(
            new Uri("https://nl-joinadfstest.joinadfstest.local/adfs/ls/"),
            uri); // 1st url is single logout service binding from adfs metadata
        }
      }
```

(`ResetCookie` is a helper function that clears a response cookie and sets its expiration in the past)

Comment: The IE issue was due to the fact that ADFS is configured from the box to attempt WIA instead of ADFS forms-based auth for that browser specifically. This PowerShell cmd on the ADFS server shows the browsers for which this is done:
`Get-AdfsProperties | select -ExpandProperty WIASupportedUserAgents`
To disable WIA for all browsers, change the setting to only non-browser clients:
`Set-AdfsProperties -WIASupportedUserAgents ("MSAuthHost/1.0/In-Domain","MSIPC","Windows Rights Management Client")`

This fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, no idea whether this works: Isn't there a way to get at the actual XML (which is empty in your case) and modify it at runtime through the classes in [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.configuration.aspx)?

Alternatively, some of the things in the XML you can modify at the time the sign-in request is sent out, in [the RedirectingToIdentityProvider event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.web.wsfederationauthenticationmodule.redirectingtoidentityprovider.aspx) by modifying the SignInRequestMessage

Comment: Not using WsFederationAuthenticationModule, the idea is to not touch Web.config for registering modules or IdentityModel configuration. Will look into the runtime configuration changes you mentioned, have found some other tis regarding writing Custom IssuerTokenValidators etc. If anything works out, I'll post it on SO as a reference.